# Cannot connect to the business Layer which is in the form of DLL in Bin folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

How do i call the Businesslayer that is in the bin folder as a DLL. 'BusinessLogic' is my dll.

```
namespace BusinessLogic
{
    public class BizLogic
    {
         string DbConnString = DbConnectionStrings.GetDbConnectionString();
         public Dataset SignIn(string Username, string Password)
         {
              string strReturn = string.Empty;
              DataSet pds = new DataSet();
              try
              {
                  SqlParameter[] parameters = new SqlParameter[]
                  {
                      new SqlParameter("@UserName", UserName )
                     ,new SqlParameter("@Password", Password )                                 
                  };
                  SqlHelper.FillDataset(DbConnString, System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure, "RepSignIn", pds, new string[] { "SignIn" }, parameters);
                  return pds;

              }
              catch (Exception ex)
              {

                  return null;
              }
         }
    }
}
```

The below part of the code used to work earlier but i changed the database from SQl 2008 R2 Express to 2008 R2 Web Edition with Windows Authentication, it stopped working. I cannot debug because its a DLL and when i have the Quickwatch on BusinssLogic, i see an error "       BusinessLogic   'BusinessLogic' is a 'namespace', which is not valid in the given context
". This is in VS 2008.

```
DataSet ds = new BusinessLogic.BizLogic().SignIn(string Username, string Password);
```

Can someone please help me what is that i am missing. The connectionString in Web.config is like this

```
namespace BusinessLogic
{
public class DbConnectionStrings
{
    private const string dbConnectionString = "ConnectionString";
    public static string GetDbConnectionString()
    {
        return GetConnectionStringFromConfigFile(dbConnectionString);
    }
    private static string GetConnectionStringFromConfigFile(string ConnectionName)
    {
        string connstring = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            connstring = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings[ConnectionName];
        }
        catch 
        { 
        }
        return connstring;
    }
    public DbConnectionStrings()
    {

    }
}
}
```

Please let me know if you need to know anything else to guide me! 
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Are you running as an ASP.NET impersonated user or are you running as yourself? This can make a difference. Also, check that you can connect to the database from SQL Server Management Studio to rule out a permissions issue for your account.

Comment: This sounds like a reference issue and has nothing to do with the sql changes you made.

Comment: @banging I have thought the same. Please look at my edits to the question where i added more about connection string and how the code is calling.

Comment: @CameronTinker I can connect to the database well. Is it because of the connection string or something. :-(

Comment: There will never be a "namespace" error message due to change in SQL server. Check your references. It's a reference issue.